# Tutorial for using snappyHexMesh with a STL file in OpenFOAM

Tags: openfoam

I have created a vehicle and output a STL file. First I want to use snappyHexMesh to convert the STL file to the proper format for OpenFOAM. Then I want to run a few airflow simulations

I am using OpenFOAM's 5.x and my case directory is here: https://github.com/anujgoyal/openfoam

Slide 13 of this presentation: http://openfoamwiki.net/images/f/f0/Final-AndrewJacksonSlidesOFW7.pdf says that 5 requirements are needed:

- Geometry data (stl, nas, obj) in **constant/triSurface/Simple Car CFD.STL** [DONE]
- Dictionary file **system/snappyHexMeshDict** [DONE, don't know if it is correct]
- Hexahedral base mesh (decomposed if running in parallel) [?, don't know where to start]
- Dictionary file **system/decomposeParDict** for parallel runs [?, I have a large Xeon system so I would like to use parallel runs]
- All system dictionaries (e.g **controlDict**, **fvSchemes**, **fvSolutions**) [?, don't know what the minimal set of parameters are]

I am having some trouble understanding what values should be in the Hexahedral base mesh, controlDict, fvSchemes and fvSolutions - does anyone have any recommendations? or could you point me to some detailed tutorials that they recommend?

[image]

Comment: have you already seen [this](http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Main_ContribExamples/2DsHM), [this](https://www.hpc.ntnu.no/display/hpc/OpenFOAM+-+Spillway+Tutorial) and [this](https://www.hpc.ntnu.no/display/hpc/OpenFOAM+-+Airfoil+Calculations)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `snappyHexMeshDict` is incomplete.
Save `.stl` file name without spaces.
I think you should modifiy `$FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible/simpleFoam/motorBike/`
case for this simulation.